# Upgrading from VS 2013 to 2019: Running/Debugging a VS 2013 MVC 5 with EF6 in VS 2019 causing lazy load errors

Tags: entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'm trying to abandon using VS 2013 and run/debug our app in VS 2019.  It's an MVC 5 app (.NET 4.7.2) that uses EF6 (code first).  I can start it up and it loads a page.  The problem is, it seems to not be able to load child objects or collections when an entity is loaded when that's needed.  We lazy load every child off a loaded entity like that for the most part.  They are always null.  Even when stepping through this, and putting the entity in a watch, when I look at any child object or collection property on it, it shows this error message:

"The metadata for 'EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-[my project name here]' is invalid. If you are debugging a minidump, you may be able to fix this problem by collecting a new minidump with heap and evaluating the expression again."

...although I'm not sure that has anything to do with them not loading when viewing in watch or hovering over them.  We're not using an EDMX or anything like that either, so I'm not sure what it's doing there. What's strange is that our build in devops uses VS 2017 anyway for building it (though I want to in dev and eventually build, move to 2019), and we haven't had trouble running that in production.  Thanks!